# Adding Multiple Nested Data in ASP.NET MVC using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, model

I have been to work on an implementation where I have a base class with a collection object of an another class. IT is quite similar to the implementation found on this [link](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/640_Adding_Multiple_Nested_Data_in_ASP_NET_MVC_Application.aspx). There is one small difference between the site's implementation and mine. Since I have lots of input elements, creating them line by line will not be feasible. So I implemented a jQuery tab which loads the content from div. The div calls custom controls using Html.RenderPartial. All said and done, it works fine until this step. Using jQuery, I try to change the name property using the following code.

```
            $('#' + id + ' input[id^="Applicant_"]').each(function() {
            var nameChange = this.id;
            var objectName = this.id.replace('Applicant_', '');
            nameChange = nameChange.replace('Applicant_', 'Application.Applicants');
            nameChange = nameChange.replace(objectName, '');
            nameChange = nameChange + '[' + tabCounter + '].' + objectName;
            $(this).attr("name", nameChange);
            //this.id = nameChange;
            //this.name = nameChange;
        });
```

Once the html is rendered on IE8, I can see the elements name unchanged, however there is a new attribute called submitName, which I am assuming is the one getting submitted. For some reason just like article I am not getting multiple elements. I am not sure what I am missing.

Here are more details

I am using Visual Studio 2008 with ASP.NET MVC2. The Base model is

```
public class Application {

        private IList<Applicant> applicants = new List<Applicant>();

        public virtual IList<Applicant> ApplicantsList
        {
            get { return applicants; }
            set { applicants = value; }
        }

}

public class Applicant {

        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        public virtual string LName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        public virtual string FName { get; set; }
}
```

The main aspx contains the following code.

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/UserControls/Application/Edit/ContactInformation.ascx"); %>
```

The code to change the name is already given above. The submit names are getting generated correctly the way it should. But for some reason when I do a submit to the controller action, the number of elemtnts under Applicant are always 0. I tried manually hardcoding with 3 elements and I got the same result.

I downloaded the article and tested it and it is working as mentioned in the article. I am not sure if I am doing anything different.

Any help would be appreciated.

***UPDATE:***

To make my life a little easier for testing, I hardcoded the following html into the cretae aspx page

```
<input type="text" name="ApplicationID" value="1" />                
<input type="text" name="Application.ApplicantsList[0].LName" value="LName-0" />
<input type="text" name="Application.ApplicantsList[1].LName" value="LName-1" />
<input type="text" name="Application.ApplicantsList[2].LName" value="LName-2" />
```

The code should , when submitted, have model.ApplicationID as 1 and the count for Application.ApplicantsList should be 3. The application ID is correctly getting submitted, however the collection is not.

Comment: Can you add what the html looks like before the submit happens?

Comment: For testing, I harcoded some html elements in to the aspx page. I am ending up with the same result. Does this help ?

Comment: Please post your controller action? Also, where is your model class that contains `ApplicationID` and `Application`? Right now, those text boxes can bind to nothing else you have posted.

Comment: There is not much in the controller right now. The controller has two methods CreatePartner, where one accepts the Application model and other one does not have anything. As for the model, I have posted both Application and Applicant model classes above.

Comment: The issue has been partially resolved. I got the submit to work with the hard coded elements. I changed Application to Model as it is referred to in the aspx page and the values got submitted without issues. However, now I have a new problem. For some reason, IE is not chaning the name attribute so jQuery is creating a new attribute called submitName and it is not working with the submission. Any idea any one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. However I am not exactly sure what the difference is. This is how I had referred to the elements in the aspx Application.ApplicantList[0].Name. Since in an APSX the Model refers to the base model I changed the line to Model.ApplicantList[0] and it started working. Is there a difference between Model and Application. I am assuming putting Model submits the object created for the page and putting Application creates a new object when submitting. Would that be a correct assumption ?